# Rotating 'a' elements with transforms

Tags: css, transform

Why doesn't CSS3 transforms work on **a** (anchor) elements ?

```
<a id="a" href="#">Rotate This</a>
#a
{
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your anchor in div and then rotate it. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zYvt/)

```
<div><a id="a" href="#">Rotate This</a></div>
```

@Byscripts said right that inline elements e.g. a, span are not supported with transforms.

Comment: No need to add a div. Just appy `display: block;` to `<a>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Rotate doesn't work on inline elements

Comment: Right, just turn your anchor into a block and you should be able to rotate away.